# Using sp_executesql with SSRS parameters as a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I use the following query in an SSRS dataset to create a pivot table which return data for years that are not specific. I.e I always return data for the last 3 years.

Here is the code

```
IF @filter = 'All'
    BEGIN  
       DECLARE @SQLEXP1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
       DECLARE @Y1 AS INT;
       DECLARE @Y2 AS INT;
       DECLARE @Y3 AS INT;
       DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
       DECLARE @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
       DECLARE @cols3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
       SET @Y1 = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3;
       SET @Y2 = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2;
       SET @Y3 = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1;
       SET @cols1 = N'['+CAST(@Y1 AS NVARCHAR(10))+N']';
       SET @cols2 = N'['+CAST(@Y2 AS NVARCHAR(10))+N']';
       SET @cols3 = N'['+CAST(@Y3 AS NVARCHAR(10))+N']';
       SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ITEMNMBR
           , CAST('' AS VARCHAR(80)) AS ITEMDESC
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS QTYAVAILABLE
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS QTYSOLDYTD
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS QTYSOLD
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS FISCALYEAR
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS YEAR1
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS YEAR2
           , CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS YEAR3;
       SET @SQLEXP1 = 'SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT ITEMNMBR
                             ,ITEMDESC
                             ,QTYAVAILABLE
                             ,QTYSOLDYTD
                             ,QTYSOLD
                             ,FISCALYEAR 
                        FROM VIEW_SALES_ITEM_FOR_PLANNING_BY_YEAR 
                        WHERE FISCALYEAR >= YEAR(GETDATE())-3 ) T0 
                    PIVOT (sum(qtysold) for FISCALYEAR in ('+@cols1+','+@cols2+','+@cols3+')) T1 
                    WHERE itemnmbr in ( '+' '+@itemno+')';
       PRINT @SQLEXP1
       EXEC Sp_executesql @SQLEXP1;
    END;
```

My problem is with the item in bold. The variable @itemno is an SSRS parameter. No matter how I configure it I alsways get an error when I run the report. Something to the effect of there is an error near ','. How do I get my SSRS parameter to work in the context of using an sp_executesql command?

Comment: Jesus! Please try to format that monster.

Comment: you can not use variable @itemno in "In Clause"  if it is comma separated value , use some function (split)

Comment: What is the value of @itemno

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert itemno to a string and concatenate it into the query string.

'select * from table where itemno = '+cast(@itemno as varchar(10))+'''